# Removing JGroups startup message : GMS

Tags: java, jgroups

On startup JGroups 2.7.0. GA writes to *System.out* a message along the lines of:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address is 10.0.3.35:48641 (cluster=blabla)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to either suppress it or redirect it using Log4j ( which the rest of the framework uses ).

Ideas?

---

I don't want to redirect System.out by itself since that usually causes more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the printing of the GMS address by setting in your XML

> <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" ...>

Works on JGroups 2.5.1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i managed to do print GMS string to logs.

First disable

```
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false">
```

then,

```
String clusterName = channel.getClusterName();
String clusterAddress = channel.getAddressAsString();
String localAddress = channel.getProtocolStack()
        .dumpStats()
        .get("UDP")
        .get("local_physical_address")
        .toString();

StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
String GMS = String.format("GMS: address=%s, cluster=%s, physical address=%s", 
        clusterAddress, 
        clusterName, 
        localAddress
);
logger.info("{}", GMS);
```

Works with **4.2.3.Final** version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect System.out to log4j that makes no sense. After all how would log4j print anything ? It would get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I meant was not redirecting System.out - I specified that, but redirect that single JGroups message.

Comment: There is some shenanigans going on with STDOUT in JBoss. When you print something to System.out, you get a log entry in the log4j log like "15:32:51,919 [] INFO  [STDOUT] blah blah". So *something* is redirecting stdout and assigning it to a dedicated log4j category.

Comment: @Skaffman
What i meant is since the original real undecorated handle to Sysout is wrapped its a mess to attempt to capture Sys.out prints. After all where would you print them  - to itself  which result in that being caught again - etc... it doesnt end. If you had the original Sysout then one could do whatever.

Its not hard to capture Sysout prints simply replace the original but its important to keep a handle on the original so you can print to it when you so wish.